# Search Text from Content and replace by php script as PLUGINs

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to build a wordpress-like plugin for my own CMS using str_replace. So when user saves something like '[do_something]' into page content, it will be replaced by a prebuild function.

example:

```
<?php function do_something() {
 // search database and display something
}

<?php
  echo str_replace("[do_something]","<?php do_something(); ?>",$page_content);
?>
```

However using echo it returns

```
"<?php do_something(); ?>"
```

as text instead of php script and fails to execute.

Any suggestion?

## UPDATED

So finally, I have come up with this:

```
function plugin($page_content){
$plugins = array(   
'[function1]' => 'function1();',
'[function2]' => 'fucntion2();'
);

foreach($plugins as $plugin => $function) {
  if (strpos($page_content, $plugin) !== false) {
    eval($function);
    break;
    }
}
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
    eval(str_replace('[do_something]', 'do_something();', $page_content));
?>
```

But please remember that using `eval` especially with user's input is a very bad practise.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But can you share with me more why it is a bad practice? I mean it only executes a predefined function I made.

Comment: Eval runs the PHP code that you put inside. And you never know what a user can put into your eval function. For example somebody can find a way to put there a PHP code that removes all files on the server.